# How to send an additional request to endpoint after each test case

Tags: testing, chatbot, botium-box

I’m currently looking at Botium Box, and I’m wondering if it is possible to send an additional request to our endpoint after each test case? Let me give you some background information about how we set up the HTTP(S)/JSON connector in Botium Box and how we are sending information to our bot:

HTTP(S) endpoint:
https://MyChatBotsEndpoint.com/?userinput={{msg.messageText}}

HTTP method: POST

We also send cookies through the header template in the request builder. Like this:

```
{
    "Cookie": "JSESSIONID={{context.sessionId}}"
}
```

The response is given back in JSON.

When a test ends (when it is successful but **also** when it fails), we need to send an additional request to our endpoint. The endpoint URL of that request should look like this:

https://MyChatBotsEndpoint.com/endsession

The header should include the cookie as described before.

Is there a way to achieve this in Botium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Botium has many extension points to plug in your custom functionality. In this case, I guess the [SIMPLEREST_STOP_HOOK](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector#SIMPLEREST_START_HOOK/SIMPLEREST_STOP_HOOK) is the best choice.

Write a small javascript file calling your endpoint, and register is with the **SIMPLEREST_STOP_HOOK** capability in botium.json. The *context* (session context from the HTTP/JSON connector) is part of the hook arguments.

in *botium.json*:

```
...
"SIMPLEREST_STOP_HOOK": "my-stop-hook.js"
...
```

*my-stop-hook.js:*

```
const request = require('request')

module.exports = ({ context }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: 'https://MyChatBotsEndpoint.com/endsession',
      headers: {
        Cookie: "JSESSIONID=" + context.sessionId
      }
    }, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This works really well. But I wonder, is it possible to automatically pull the endpoint URL from the HTTP(S) Endpoint Configuration (in the HTTP(S) / JSON connector) in Botium Box, so that I could potentially have multiple chatbots up and running in Botium Box? Right now the my-stop-hook.js is hard coded for just one endpoint.

Comment: You can use the SIMPLEREST_INIT_CONTEXT capability to add the url to call to the session context and make it available to the stop hook.